# How does java lambdas external references work?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm wondering how does lambdas external references work. Let me explain:

Suppose i have this supplier implementation and this model class :

```
public class TestSupplierImpl implements Supplier<Boolean> {

    public Predicate<Integer> predicate;
    public TestSupplierModel model;

    public TestSupplierImpl() {
        this.predicate = i -> model.something.equals(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean get() {
        return predicate.test(3);
    }
}


    class TestSupplierModel {
        public Integer something;

        public TestSupplierModel(Integer something) {
            this.something = something;
        }
    }
```

Then i execute the following code:

```
    TestSupplierImpl test = new TestSupplierImpl(); // line 1
    test.model = new TestSupplierModel(3); // line 2
    Boolean resultado = test.get(); // line 3
```

Line 1: creating a new instance of TestSupplierImpl. This new instance's predicate has a null reference of *model*. This makes sense because at the moment of creation of the predicate, model reference is null.
Line 2:  assign to variable *model* a new instance of TestSupplierModel.
Line 3: test.predicate now has *model* reference with the new assigned value. **Why is this ?**

I don't understand why ,when I changed *model* reference, the predicate updates its model reference to the new one. How is that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Because the lambda captures `this` (i.e. the instance of `TestSupplierImpl`) and `model` actually refers to `TestSupplierImpl.this.model`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense if you rewrote your `TestSupplierImpl()` constructor as follows?

```
    public Predicate<Integer> predicate;
    public TestSupplierModel model;

    public TestSupplierImpl() {
        // same effect as this.predicate = i -> model.something.equals(i);
        this.predicate = new Predicate<Integer>() {
            public boolean test(Integer i) {
                return model.something.equals(i);
            }
        };
        
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean get() {
        return predicate.test(3);
    }
```

So here is the order of things.

```
        // the constructor is run and the test method defined BUT NOT executed.
        TestSupplierImpl test = new TestSupplierImpl(); // line 1
       
        // Now you define model
        test.model = new TestSupplierModel(3); // line 2
        
        // Then you execute the predictate via get()
        Boolean resultado = test.get(); // line 3
```

`model and something` aren't required until you issue the `get()` method.  By that time they are already defined.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i got it :) .
The thing that i don't understand is why lambdas external refferences sometimes have to be final/effectively final and in other places ( link in the above example) it doesn't need to be final.

Comment: It has to do with concurrency issues.  Local variables are stored on the stack while instance fields are stored in the heap.  If a thread were to access a value from a lambda that was on the stack it could be accessing one that is not longer in scope or was de-allocated.  If they are effectively final they can't change so it's essentially a copy. It's similar in that local variables are immune to interaction within threads while instance fields are not.

Comment: excellent, i wrote down another example and i figured it out. thanks WJS for the explanation !